# Blanks filter doesn't works

Tags: reporting, filters, custom-reports

I created a Salesforce report and want a field to be filtered to only show the ones containing certain text.

I used a filter with contains: MXN APT SET

It shows those (about 800 results) but also the ones that are with "-" (Over 900k results!)

And I can't find a way to filter the outcome without those "-"

I had tried adding another filter using.

- Does not contain: "",-
- Not equal to: "",-

But still not working.
Any Idea how I can get rid of those blanks?

[image: "-" Reults]

Answer (score 0):

The [Notes about Filtering on Types of Fields and Values](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.notes_on_entering_filter_criteria.htm&type=5) should help you here. Basically, when you configure the filters for your report choose the field and the “not equal to” operators, leaving the third field blank. There's also a video from Salesforce Support on filtering our these blank values across a range of different places [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zQuXTeN5vg).